# Getting data from a table after validating from other table mvc .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working in entity framework. Problem is i want to get those transaction from table A(AssetTransactions) which shoud not match to attribute LoggedInMonth of table B(ReopeningValidations). Please give me idea or alternative query

```
from transaction in dbContext.AssetsTransctions join validation on 
dbContext.Reopening Validations on transaction.TransId equals 
validation.AssetTransaction_TransId 
where ((transaction.PurchaseDate <= pDAte && 
transaction.IsAvailable.Equals(true)) && 
(!(validation.LoggedInMonth.Equals(loggedMonthYear)))) select transaction
```

Comment: Is there really any reason to use EF if you're more or less just feeding pseudo SQL into it?

Comment: can you explain what's wrong with this query? Give an example of expected vs actual results?

Comment: @timothyclifford Because EF will automatically parse the SQL result into .NET objects for you. This is the _query expression_ version of creating a LINQ query. It is totally valid, though not as performant as using the LINQ extension methods.

Comment: This query return null if the first table have data and 2nd one is empty. I want if 2nd table is empty then first table also returns filtered records